# ERROR 1064: is there a mysql create table to insert a foreign key? I get a syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

when I am creating a table and inserting a foreign key, I get this error "ERROR 1064 (4200)" of syntax, I don't know if I am writing it wrong or if I need something else to add it to the table.

### Code:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (id_orders INT NOT NULL, date DATE NOT NULL, id_client INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES client(id_client));
```

---

I expected the data output to be correct and not give me an error. since I am connecting a primary key with a foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The create statement should be  like this

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id_orders INT NOT NULL
, date DATE NOT NULL
, id_client INT
, CONSTRAINT fk_client FOREIGN KEY (id_client)
  REFERENCES client(id_client) );
```